# Bayesian network calculation to find probability for independent events?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I have the following Bayesian network:

[image: Sketch of Bayes net without CPTs]

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate some of the conditional probabilities between nodes, in particular when they are independent. For instance, how would you calculate `P(C=true, G=true|H=false)`? I'm aware that I have to use the Bayes rule and the conditional probability formula. How do you go about setting up the equations for each of these and do you use variable elimination for any of these?

Comment: I don't feel knowledgeable enough to write a proper answer, but I think it can be done by iteratively going through the network, starting with nodes with no dependencies. In this case A and D have no dependencies, then from these two one can estimate B, C, E and F, and finally G and H. Note that the example `P(C=true, G=true|H=false)` is trivial: `P(C=true, G=true|H=false)=P(C=true, G=true)` since nothing depends on H.

Comment: @Erwan Yes, that's what I was thinking too! In general, when we have nodes that are independent, say even a simpler example in this case as `P(C=true|F=true)`, would I essentially only want to calculate `P(C=true)` and take into account any nodes that `C` may be dependent upon?